# Google Drive iOS SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to check if a folder exists AND only if it doesn't exist create a new one.  However, that folder could be a subfolder of root or another folder.  So how can I do something like mkdirs on Unix where you give it a path and it creates all directories in the path?

BTW - The SDK is a bit frustrating to use as it appears to not have a way to use filesystem paths.  Instead, you have to lots of queries and callbacks which is quite messy.  W

This is what I use to create a folder:

```
- (void)createFolder:(NSString *)folderName completion:(void (^)(GTLDriveFile * file, NSError *))handler {
    NSLog(@"createFolder:%@ completion:", folderName);

    GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
    folder.title = folderName;
    folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
    [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile *updatedFile, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Created folder");
            handler(updatedFile, nil);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            handler(updatedFile, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way.

The *nix filesystem is hierarchical, whereas the Google Drive filesystem is not. There are things which the UI and API refers to a "folders", but these are little more than tags/labels.

So if you want a folder hierarchy, you'll need to build it yourself (probably as you've figured out). There are no shortcuts.

You will probably find starting your app by doing a search for all folders

```
q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

is the way to go

Comment: Well one problem I am seeing is that the existence check and creation call are not atomic.  It is possible for one call to createFolder: to be executing the check before another call finishes the create.

Comment: That's correct. The thing that the marketing name "Drive" implies is analogous to a hard drive, is in fact farms of loosely coupled servers, with lots of async updates going on. If your app embraces that paradigm, it's not too bad. Any app which attempts to treat Drive as a drive, will come unstuck.